# Disable screenshot

Tags: android

I am  using below code to view image with the help of default gallery,

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(photoURI, "image/*");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(intent);
```

But at the same time  i want to disable screenshot when users view image using gallery. I can disable screenshot directly for my app screen but can't do when image is viewed from gallery.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  If you need that functionality, don't use gallery and write your own display code.  Although that's 99% useless-  if a user really wants to screenshot his own phone, he can.  Worst case he can grab a second phone and take a picture.